# How could an intergalactic spacefaring civilization kidnap a member of another intergalactic spacefaring civilization without causing war?

Tags: science-fiction

In my story, there is an alien civilization whom the people of the Sol system refer to as the Chrondosians. Most Chrondosian technological advancement can be attributed to direct contact with one of a triumvirate of omnipotent entities thousands of years ago by a "prehistoric" Chrondosian named Amentuk. Because of the monumental and unprecedented advancement of technology due to Amentuk's teachings, the Chrondosians worship and idolize these entities, which they call the Autochthones.

On Earth, a human woman is (unbeknownst to her) the eminent scholar on the Authochthones, so much so that, against all probability, she knows more about them than the Chrondosians do. She's a xeno-linguist/archaeologist, an academic.

A clandestine militaristic faction of Chrondosian religious zealots catches wind of this human woman, and decide they need to kidnap her in order to leverage her knowledge.

For context, both civilizations can travel "faster than light".

My question is: how could this rogue faction successfully kidnap this woman without rousing the suspicions of either civilization?

Comment: (1) Autochthone is very much too similar to the word autochthon which means "native". (It is the Greek equivalent of the Latin "native". Note the different metaphor in Greek vs. Latin.) (2) A woman being abducted is not really a *casus belli*, or else all nations would be at war with all nations. (3) The only woman ever whose abduction resulted in a war was Helen of Troy (or of Sparta, depending on your point of view), and the gossip is she went willingly.

Comment: if from seeing real life examples, it would likely caused a crisis. except if the abducting govs offer something in exchange of the woman. perhaps a resources, or even bribe corrupts officials.

Comment: "Interstellar civilization" does not tell me very much. I would want to know how much interaction there is between systems, species, and so on. Contact every 10 years presents a much different situation from contact every 10 days.

Comment: @AlexP I feel like you're ignoring the fact that this woman is an incredibly important resource, not just some random person.

Comment: "Rousing the suspicions" is one thing.  "Going to war" is quite another.  Enough plausible deniability and politics as usual and you can rouse all the suspicions in the world without starting a war.

Comment: There are probably a literally thousands or millions of eminent scholars, across all fields. So she may be eminent, but honestly, a scholar on some alien species' ancient contacts/deities, its like an eminent scholar on Mayan gods. How many do you know? How many people would notice if one of the best went missing? How many would immediately think "alien kidnap" rather than say "human abduction" or "lost" or just "dunno where she is, missing person". 2 days curiosity slot in the news  and pics of the crying family and perplexed colleagues. That's actually my guess how it goes. Sorry. .....

Comment: .....So the answer is 'almost any subtle way, doesn't matter which."

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to go about it would be to pose as some sort of secretive "research society" and offer her a job. If she accepts, whisk her away to whatever corner of the galaxy you base your operations in and leave everyone on earth to believe she joined this group. You could even let her call or visit home every once in a while, to keep up the ruse.

If she doesn't accept, just kidnap her and let everyone close to her know that she accepted the job, and they won't be hearing from her for a while, and she's terribly sorry for the inconvenience but she's just been stranded with a mountain of work at her new job.

Answer (score 3):

**Doppelganger.**

The Chrondys like movies as much as we do (their own, and ours, and those of other alien species) and they have some makeup artists with real skill.  The military drafts one of their actors who is tasked with playing the role of this researcher in her absence.

The researcher is not in any movies, it turns out.  The actor is given a video of a talk she gave, as preparation.  It is actually just her introducing other speakers.

The actor does look just like the researcher now even if it has little idea how she usually acts.  And this actor is a fine actor who it turns out has watched a lot of Earth movies.  The actor decides the researcher is not up to movie par and so starts with altering its appearance; initially a little then when this is well received, substantially.  Then the actor cribs from a deep fund of knowledge of Earth movie dialogue and action to portray its subject.

Answer (score 1):

### Stage her death

As the late, great Hans Gruber once said: "When you steal \$600, you can just disappear. But when you steal $600 *million*, they *will* find you... unless they think you're already dead."

The aliens' goal is simply this: acquire the researcher without alerting humanity to the fact that these aliens exist or have kidnapped her. They do not want a hostage.

So, the aliens should use their advanced technology to fake her death. To maximize the chances that the humans will not look very hard for an alternative explanation:

- stage the death such that there are no remains to be found (a fake corpse could be examined and revealed as fake)
- implicate other humans in her death (because people don't vanish for no reason)
- make her appear to be an innocent bystander rather than a deliberate target (because a homicide investigation will systematically disqualify every suspect)
- make it clear that she *is* dead, not simply missing (because most normal deaths are unambiguous, not open-ended mysteries)

Some ideas:

- blow up her home and make it look like a gas leak
- capture her when she's at sea and make it look like she went overboard
- blow up her workplace and make it look like a lone suicide bomber
- stage a fake vacation getaway contest to a tropical island and then abduct her during a hurricane
- blow up her most embarrassing social media post using hacking, and then abduct her; everyone will assume she went into hiding and then collapsed into a singularity under the crushing shame
- [abduct her from an airplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempus_Fugit_(The_X-Files)) that's flying over the ocean, and then ensure the plane breaks up in the air